# Is it possible to have a related articles panels by classification in Business Catalyst

Tags: business-catalyst

I'm looking to create a related articles panel on my article pages in Business Catalyst.

Is it possible with a web app item list to specify that it only shows the items from the articles own classification?

Answer (score 1):

With Liquid Markup enabled, you can read the classification(s) of the current item with `{{ this.classifications }}`¹.

The tag to list other items with the same classifications may look like this:

```
{module_webapps render="item" id="yourwebapp" filter="classified" itemId="{{ this.classifications }}"}
```

If the items have more than one classification, you'll need to do some [string manipulation](http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/dev-assets/reference#!/liquid-reference/reference/filters.html!string-filters) to get this to work.

---

¹ *Only on the item's Detail view; classifications are currently not accessible in List view.*